# RoR, Mongoid: How to update nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, mongoid

I have the model anwer_pair.rb

```
class AnswerPair
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :question
  embedded_in :survey
  field :answer1, type: String
  field :answer2, type: String
  ...
  field :correct, type: Boolean, default: true
  ...
  def new(answer1 = "answer1", answer2 = "answer2", correct = false)
    @answer1 = answer1
    @answer2 = answer2
    @correct = correct
  end
  ...
end
```

which is nested in question.rb

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  field :name, type: String
  ...
  embeds_many :answer_pairs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_pairs, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

Using a form to save a question to the database works fine (I use mongoid). Now I'd like to add some more answer pairs to the question, before it is updated or created. For that reason I invoke the following method in "update" and "create" in questions_controller.rb

```
 class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
 ...
 def update
   ...
   fill_up_answer_pairs(@question)
   ...
 end

 def create
    ...
    fill_up_answer_pairs(@question)
    ...
 end
 ...
 def fill_up_answer_pairs(question)
    if(question.answer_pairs.any?)
      question.answer_pairs.where(correct: false) do |pair|
        pair.delete
      end
      question.answer_pairs.where(correct: true) do |pair1|
        question.answer_pairs.where(correct: true) do |pair2|
          if(pair1.answer1 != pair2.answer1 && pair1.answer2 != pair2.answer2) 
            question.add_to_set(:answer_pairs, AnswerPair.new(pair1.answer1, pair2.answer2, false)) 
          end
        end
      end 
      # having "question.update_attributes(question.answer_pairs)" here would cause a "NameError ... undefined method `keys' for #<Array ..."
    end
  end
```

but it doesn't save the added answer pairs. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th following changes fixed the problem:
After the where clauses I forgot the "each"s and I changed the new method of answer_pair.rb to

```
def self.buildnew(answer1 = "answer1", answer2 = "answer2", correct = false)
    ap = AnswerPair.new
    ap.answer1 = answer1
    ap.answer2 = answer2
    ap.correct = correct
    return ap
end
```

Using question.update_attributes is not necessary.